# Jerky behavior on UIView when hiding a UIStatusBar?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view that is placed over a UIScrollView which moves according to the UIScrollView's content offset. I achieve this by adjusting the view's vertical constraint in `scrollViewDidScroll` :

```
topViewTopConstraint.constant = -scrollView.contentOffset.y - topView.frame.height
```

The `topView` moves great until the opaque status bar needs to become hidden, which is when it meets a certain threshold. In my VC's `scrollViewDidScroll`, i achieve it using the following code

```
if -scrollView.contentOffset.y <= thresholdY {
                self.statusBarHidden = true
            } else {
                self.statusBarHidden = false
            }
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

When the scrollView's content offset for Y reaches the `thresholdY`, the `topView` jerks.

I've  put a log on the `-scrollView.contentOffset.y` and it seems to jump 20 pixels during the jerking. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: My guess is that the total screensize changed when you hid the StatusBar, so the os is updating the content offset accordingly... you may need to take the current screen size into account on your code, if that is the case (by Screensize, I mean the view that is parent to your scrollview).

Answer (score 2):

Is the topView constraint based on the top guide line? The problem is that the top constraint is probably been defined based on the bottom of the top guide line which is bottom of status bar. When you hide the status bar that line moves. So when the offset meets your threshold it hides the status bar which then makes the if statement untrue which turns the status bar back on and so on.

You can probably define the top constraint in relation to the bottom guide line or something else that is constant.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue in Swift today when rotating a scrollview within a VC, I fixed the 20px offset when rotating into landscape by calling `scrollView.contentSize = size` in the `viewWillTransition` like so

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        scrollView.contentSize = size
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    }
```